# Buttons inside JQuery DateTime Picker Panel

Tags: jquery, button, datetimepicker

I am using JQUery date time picker [This One](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) version v2.3.4 which pops up as soon as the relevant input box gets the focus which is fine. What I want is to have **TWO** buttons inside the date time picker panel e.g. "**Apply**" on which I could call some **function** and **another** button to **Close or cancel** the picker. I tried "showButtonPanel" :true but I don't see any default button showing up.

Here is how I am initializing the date time picker

```
 $(".datetime").datetimepicker({
    format: 'd/m/Y H:00', lang: 'en', 
    validateOnBlur: false,
    showButtonPanel:true,
    closeText:"Apply"
});
```

I noticed that the option "showButtonPanel:true" only works with datepicker not with datetimepicker.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you tried?

Comment: I have posted the exact code :)

Comment: Is there a typo? `$(".datetime").datetimepicker({` should be `$(".datetime").datepicker({`

Comment: No its not a typo it is indeed .datetimepicker as I am using the picker for both date and time.

Comment: Ah ok. Didn´t knew this one.

Comment: always add the link to plugin page